# Maximum number of circles

Tags: geometry, combinations

Given 11 points, of which 5 lie on one circle, other than these 5, no 4 lie on one circle. Then the maximum number of circles that can be drawn so that each contains atleast three of the given points is ?

Comment: Does the fact that 5 of them lie on one circle really change the problem? When you say that no 4 lie on one circle, do you mean to say that no 4 are contained by the same circle?

Answer (score 1):

Well, three points define a circle. So calculate the number of triples; that would be $\binom{11}3$. Then subtract the number of triples which all produce the same circle - that would be $\binom53$ - and add 1.

The problem statement says nothing of the possibility that some triple may lie on a *straight line*, in which case it does not define a circle. Apparently, your instructors didn't think of this possibility, so neither should you.